# Why this file do not get downloaded into a specified location?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, web, command-line, wget

I am downloading the file in this [link](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/5_5/rel/installers/cuda_5.5.22_linux_32.run). I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and I used the below command to download it.

```
wget -p /home/ubuadmin/CUDA http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/5_5/rel/installers/cuda_5.5.22_linux_32.run
```

Below is my command line input and output.

```
root@ubuserver3:/home/ubuadmin# wget -p /home/ubuadmin/CUDA http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/5_5/rel/installers/cuda_5.5.22_linux_32.run
/home/ubuadmin/CUDA: Scheme missing.
--2014-03-11 08:06:28--  http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/5_5/rel/installers/cuda_5.5.22_linux_32.run
Resolving developer.download.nvidia.com (developer.download.nvidia.com)... 23.62.239.35, 23.62.239.27
Connecting to developer.download.nvidia.com (developer.download.nvidia.com)|23.62.239.35|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 686412076 (655M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: `developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/5_5/rel/installers/cuda_5.5.22_linux_32.run'

100%[======================================>] 686,412,076  663K/s   in 16m 56s

2014-03-11 08:23:24 (660 KB/s) - `developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/5_5/rel/installers/cuda_5.5.22_linux_32.run' saved [686412076/686412076]

FINISHED --2014-03-11 08:23:24--
Total wall clock time: 16m 56s
Downloaded: 1 files, 655M in 16m 56s (660 KB/s)
```

It says the download is completed but I can't find the file in that folder. I am accessing this server remotely using PuTTY, and using WinSCP to see the file structure. What has gone wrong? Why is it missing even it is downloaded?

Comment: To set the target folder, use `-P` (upper case) instead of `-p`.

Comment: @fedorqui: Please provide your answer as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the target folder, use `-P` (upper case) instead of `-p`.

From `man wget`:

> **-P prefix**
>
> --directory-prefix=prefix
>
> Set directory prefix to prefix. The directory prefix is the directory
>   where all other files and subdirectories will be saved to, i.e. the
>   top of the retrieval tree.  The default is . (the current directory).

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /home/ubuadmin

mkdir test

cd test

wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/5_5/rel/installers/cuda_5.5.22_linux_32.run
```

after use this command

```
stat cuda_5.5.22_linux_32.run
```

and show output

Answer (score 0):

The "p" needs to be capitalized. Keep in mind Linux is case sensitive in most aspects.